# Authorization across subdomains

Tags: go, subdomain, multi-tenant, authorize

I have a case:

- In theta.smatyx.com:
  Set 1 domain-match cookie (with domain: .smatyx.com), with value of 1 short-lived
  jwt, signed with theta.smatyx.com).
- In mylong.smatyx.com:
  Redirect to page [mylong.smatyx.com](http://mylong.smatyx.com/), at this time the above short-lived cookie is still kept. [mylong.smatyx.com](http://mylong.smatyx.com/) will request to login, based on the above short-lived cookie. The server returns the session cookie.
  There are 2 cases: session cookie will be cleared or will be used for mylong.smatyx...

I have used http://localhost:8080 for one service and http://localhost:8081 for another.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZtvP.png)

How can I retrieve UserID based on the session cookie and shared between subdomains?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you have to ask, you should not implement authentication yourself. Use OIDC instead. Keycloak or Dex are not hard to set up and use and authenticate a user to multiple subdomains.